# How can i set minimum font size in puppeteer or chromium?

Tags: puppeteer, chromium

I am using puppeteer to generate pdf.
The pdf generated by puppeteer is different from that generated by using window.print().

I found that the minimum font size in chrome is 12px but chromium is 8px.
I think that's why they look different.
I see 11px in chromium (headless false).

The minimum font size for chrome Chinese is 12px.
but the chromium is 8px.

so,How can i set minimum font size in puppeteer or chromium ?
if i can set the same minimum font size, the pdf should look the same.